# shapely examples use 'figures', what is this library?

Tags: python, shapely

For example

https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/polygon.py

uses a library 'figures'.  I can't seem to locate this library.  There
are several libraries on PyPi with figures in the name, but none seem correct

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 5):

It's a helper library for the shapely documentation. You can find it in the shapely [documentation source](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/blob/master/docs/code):

- [figures.py](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/blob/master/docs/code/figures.py)